# I am unable to see any performance results with this code I have built. Can someone clarify?

Tags: pine-script

//version=3

```
strategy(title="MACD example strategy", overlay=false, default_qty_value=10000)
```

// Create inputs

```
fastLen = input(title="Fast Length", type=integer, defval=12)
slowLen = input(title="Slow Length", type=integer, defval=26)
sigLen  = input(title="Signal Length", type=integer, defval=9)
```

// Get MACD values

```
[macdLine, signalLine, _] = macd(close, fastLen, slowLen, sigLen)
```

// Plot MACD values and line

```
 plot(series=macdLine, color=#6495ED, linewidth=2)
    plot(series=signalLine, color=orange, linewidth=2)

hline(price=0)
```

// Determine long and short conditions

```
longCondition  = crossover(macdLine, signalLine)
very = rsi(close,14) < 30 or rsi(close[1],14)<30
yolo = sma(close,5) > sma(close,20)
yulu = close>sma(close,200)
```

// Submit orders

```
strategy.entry(id="Long Entry", long=true, when= longCondition and very and yolo and yulu)
strategy.exit(id="Long Exit", profit=close*0.01/syminfo.mintick, loss=close*0.09/syminfo.mintick)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you have too many conflicting conditions.

You're looking for the 5 period MA to be above the 20 period MA and the close to be above the 200 period MA. Those three conditions would indicate an uptrend. The odds of finding the RSI below 30 in an uptrend aren't very likely.

When I removed your very test from the entry I got plenty of results.

Comment: Thank you for helping by providing simplified clarification.
Sir, can I get any channel of communication of yours ?